# classNameBindings not working

Tags: ember.js

In a component I have three properties defined in my `classNameBindings`:

```
classNames: ['ui-selectize'],
classNameBindings: [ 'touchDevice', 'fingerFriendly', 'selected:selected:not-selected' ]
```

What I'd expect is that if at run-time the properties 'fingerFriendly' or 'touchDevice' were true that the classnames 'finger-friendly' and 'touch-device' would be added respectfully. That is **almost** happening but I'm getting some pretty odd behaviour. Also annoying is that this DID used to work but I can't figure out what is now interfering.

So in a situation where both `touchDevice` and `fingerFriendly` are true I can look at the inspector and see the following:

[image: correctly associated to binding]

The above looks right but if I look at the classNames property I have:

[image: touch-device is included?]

I'm a little surprised that `touch-device` is showing up here considering it's not a statically bound property. However, what surprises me the most is that if *it* is included than surely `finger-friendly` should be included too, right?

For actual code you can find it all here:

https://github.com/lifegadget/ui-selectize/blob/9fe8764f4304e87c8f26323f00ccba4c16c981ba/addon/components/ui-selectize.js

Comment: Have you checked `fingerFriendly` value? Is it set to true? JSBin example would be awesome to solve problem

Comment: Yup, have checked the values.  I think one better than JSBin is the full demo that is available of this plugin at: http://development.ui-selectize.divshot.io